# move overlap images over one another to get accurate difference

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, imagemagick, image-comparison

I want to get the image Difference for the print which is captured using camera.

I tried many solution using python libraries: opencv, image-magic, etc.

The solution I found for image comparison is for better accuracy is:

1. move image : **left to right** and look for minimum difference.
2. move image : **right to left** and look for minimum difference.
3. move image : **top to bottom** and look for minimum difference.
4. move image : **bottom to top** and look for minimum difference.

Condition to capture Image :
1. **camera will never move** (mounted over a fix stand).
2. **Object is placed manually over a white sheet, thus the object will never be properly aligned**. (slight variation in angle every time, as it is manual )

Image Sample captured using camera for the bellow code :

**Image sample 1:  white Dots :**

[image: Image 1 as original image]

**Image sample 2: as original image**

[image: Image 2 with white dotes]

**Image sample 3: black dots**

[image]

**Accepted Output for print with white dots is not available, but it should only mark the difference(defect) :**

[image: Accepted output]

Currently I am using following Image-magic command for image difference:

```
compare -highlight-color black -fuzz 5% -metric AE Image_1.png Image_2.png -compose src diff.png
```

Code :

```html
import subprocess

# -fuzz 5% # ignore minor difference between two images

cmd = 'compare -highlight-color black -fuzz 5% -metric AE Input.png output.png -compose src diff.png '

subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

**Output after difference is incorrect as the comparison works pixel to pixel, it is not smart enough to mark only the real difference:**

[image: output]

The above solution which I mention  will work to get required difference as output, but there is no library or image-magic command available for such image comparison.

**Any python code OR Image-magic command for doing this?**

Comment: Are your sample images properly representative of your actual images? Do you have other samples? Why are the images not aligned - does your camera move or do you have multiple cameras? How do you move your image around looking for the best position- please show your code. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell modified.

Answer (score 7):

It seems you are doing some defect detection task. The first solution comes in my mind is the image registration technique. 
First try to take the images in the same conditions (lighting, camera angle and ...) (one of your provided images is bigger 2 pixels).

Then you should register two images and match one to the other one, like this

[image]

Then wrap them with the help of homography matrix, and generate an aligned image, in this case, the result is like this:

[image]

Then take the difference of aligned image with the query image and threshold it, the result:

[image]

As I said if you try to take your frames with more precise, the registration result will be better and cause more accurate performance.

The codes for each part: (mostly taken from [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/dc/dc3/tutorial_py_matcher.html)).

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


MAX_FEATURES = 1000
GOOD_MATCH_PERCENT = 0.5


def alignImages(im1, im2):
    # Convert images to grayscale
    im1Gray = cv2.cvtColor(im1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    im2Gray = cv2.cvtColor(im2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Detect ORB features and compute descriptors.
    orb = cv2.ORB_create(MAX_FEATURES)
    keypoints1, descriptors1 = orb.detectAndCompute(im1Gray, None)
    keypoints2, descriptors2 = orb.detectAndCompute(im2Gray, None)

    # Match features.
    matcher = cv2.DescriptorMatcher_create(cv2.DESCRIPTOR_MATCHER_BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING)
    matches = matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, None)

    # Sort matches by score
    matches.sort(key=lambda x: x.distance, reverse=False)

    # Remove not so good matches
    numGoodMatches = int(len(matches) * GOOD_MATCH_PERCENT)
    matches = matches[:numGoodMatches]

    # Draw top matches
    imMatches = cv2.drawMatches(im1, keypoints1, im2, keypoints2, matches, None)
    cv2.imwrite("matches.jpg", imMatches)

    # Extract location of good matches
    points1 = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)
    points2 = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)

    for i, match in enumerate(matches):
        points1[i, :] = keypoints1[match.queryIdx].pt
        points2[i, :] = keypoints2[match.trainIdx].pt

    # Find homography
    h, mask = cv2.findHomography(points1, points2, cv2.RANSAC)

    # Use homography
    height, width, channels = im2.shape
    im1Reg = cv2.warpPerspective(im1, h, (width, height))

    return im1Reg 
if __name__ == '__main__':

  # Read reference image
  refFilename = "vv9gFl.jpg" 
  imFilename =  "uP3CYl.jpg" 
  imReference = cv2.imread(refFilename, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) 
  im = cv2.imread(imFilename, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) 

  # Registered image will be resotred in imReg. 
  # The estimated homography will be stored in h. 
  imReg = alignImages(im, imReference)

  # Write aligned image to disk. 
  outFilename = "aligned.jpg" 
  cv2.imwrite(outFilename, imReg)
```

for image difference and thresholding: 
    alined = cv2.imread("aligned.jpg" , 0)
    alined = alined[:, :280]

```
b = cv2.imread("vv9gFl.jpg", 0 )
b = b[:, :280]

print (alined.shape)
print (b.shape)

diff = cv2.absdiff(alined, b)
cv2.imwrite("diff.png", diff)

threshold = 25
alined[np.where(diff >  threshold)] = 255
alined[np.where(diff <= threshold)] = 0

cv2.imwrite("threshold.png", diff)
```

If you have lots of images and want to do defect detecting task I suggest using Denoising Autoencoder to train a deep artificial neural network. Read more [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/324179731_Automatic_Fabric_Defect_Detection_with_a_Multi-Scale_Convolutional_Denoising_Autoencoder_Network_Model).

Comment: Can I align both the image at the centre pixel.

Comment: The centre pixel will vary with image resolution. Is is possible

Comment: No, you can not, aligning the images are not the matter, you should align the shapes on top of each other.

Comment: What if I have multiple image ? how to stack them all ?

Comment: Compare them one-by-one. Use one of the images as a reference image, the one which you are sure is the perfect one. Then use the code I provided and compare this image with all other images, one-by-one.

Comment: Is it possible to stretch those object where align is getting misplaces ?

Comment: @AliAbbasi Unable to adjust the Image-Alignment, which parameter do i need to change to **handle image alignment**  ???

Answer (score 2):

Although you do not want point-by-point processing, here is a subimage-search compare using Imagemagick. It pads one image after cropping off the black and then shifts the smaller to find the best match locations with the larger.

## crop image1:

```
convert image1.jpg -gravity north -chop 0x25 image1c.png
```

[image]

## crop and pad image2:

```
convert image2.jpg -gravity north -chop 0x25 -gravity center -bordercolor "rgb(114,151,157)" -border 20x20 image2c.png
```

[image]

## do subimage search

```
compare -metric rmse -subimage-search image2c.png image1c.png null:
1243.41 (0.0189732) @ 22,20
```

## now shift and get difference between the two images

```
convert image2c.png image1c.png -geometry +22+20 -compose difference -composite -shave 22x20 -colorspace gray -auto-level +level-colors white,red diff.png
```

[image]

ADDITION:

If you want to just use compare, then you need to add -fuzz 15% to the compare command:

```
compare -metric rmse -fuzz 15% -subimage-search image2c.png image1c.png diff.png
```

Two images are produced. The difference image is the first, so look at diff-0.png

[image]

Comment: What If I want to use **compare** rather than **convert**

Comment: `@mithil` I do not understand the question. My code does use compare. I had to use `convert ... -compose difference`, because it shows the difference much better than the results from the subimage-search compare result.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I was confused whether to select compare or convert.

Comment: You can use compare alone if you want. Just add -fuzz 15% (or whatever value you think works best). I have modified my answer to include that result.

Comment: I am getting only one Image. No such **diff-0.png**

Comment: Are you doing compare with subimage-search (as per my command and images) with one image padded. If not, then you will get only one image. But you may not have the proper shift without doing the subimage-search and so getting difference from misalignment.

Comment: I also think that the approach by `@Ali Abbasi` might be a good one. It will distort one image to match the other. This will remove any scale or rotation that is not being considered in the compare approach that just does shifts. Then you can do the difference method I posted first.